# Website redirects me at localhost (Dns error)

Tags: redirect, dns, localhost, nslookup

I'm trying to reach a website (it.rojadirecta.eu) but it redirects me at localhost. I've used the command prompt and typed "nslookup it.rojadirecta.eu" and infacts it shows my host. How can i fix that? Thanks for the help. 
[Windows 8.1]

Answer (score 0):

The reason of that is because you have the site you are looking for blocked in your `HOSTS File`. As a result, everytime you request `it.rojadirecta.eu` the `HOSTS file` translate it to your `localhost` `IP Address 127.0.0.1`.

To edit this settings, please follow this step by step tutorial:

https://www.petri.com/edit-hosts-file-windows-8

Comment: my host file is totaly clean. i suppose that rojadirecta is blocked on my country, but im not sure. I've read that on an article written in the 2014...

Comment: Not sure about that @KRower. If the site was blocked in your country, you would recieve a `Server Unreachable` error instead of a `redirect` to your `localhost`. Take into consider that this website might be blocked in the port list of your router as well.